# What is the default value for the CompressionMode enumeration for the DeflateStream constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, compression

The `DeflateStream` constructor has four different overloads - two of which take in the `CompressionLevel` enumeration, and two of which take the `CompressionMode` enumeration, as parameters.
Now, for the constructor
`DeflateStream(Stream stream, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)`, what could be the value of the `CompressionMode` enumeration? Is it `CompressionMode.Compress` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Msdn Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137322%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This constructor overload uses the compression mode Compress.

So yes, the default value is `CompressionMode.Compress`.